# Use GCM with PHP

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I've seen several posts about how to send GCM messages from my PHP server, but I can't get it working. This is my code:

```
public function test_gcm($id_user){

    // Search user's RegIds and stores them in $regids

    if(count($regids) == 0){
        echo "This user has no registered device.";
        return;
    }

    $ch = curl_init();

    $data = array(
        'data' => array('message'=>'my message', 'title'=>'message title'),
        'registration_ids' => $regids
    );      

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // WRITE JSON HEADERS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization:key=' . $apiKey)
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
}
```

I'm using the browser key. I tried the server key too, but none of them work, the curl_exec always return false. Does anybody know why is it?

EDIT: I just used 'netstat -tuanc | grep 173' on my server and performed the server call. I'm using grep 173 because if I ping android.googleapis.com I ping this ip address. The netstat didn't show any connection to that ip address when I use the curl_exec. Does that mean I'm not connecting to android.googleapis.com? Or what I'm doing is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I got it working like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396177/gcm-sending-with-curl-php
Hope it helps

Comment: Also: I made it allow calls from all IPs. Test it like that first. I used the browser key aswell.

Comment: Yours is one of the posts I checked. I modified the order to have it exactly like you, but it's still not woking. I have "Any IP allowed" for the server key and "Any referer allowed" for the browser key.

Comment: Did you remove the space between Content-type: application/json? I have no idea if this would make any defference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it. It was a firewall issue, my firewall was blocking the connection. I've added the rules to accept these messages and now it works.

Thanks to all the people that tried to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the "message" content are same or not in android code. 'message'=>'my message' should match with the message from IntentService class in android.

Comment: I'm using the demo sample provided by Google (http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html). The function GCMIntentService->onMessage just displays a static string, it doesn't check the message value.

Comment: but as u r running php server there must be some value to interact with your android code. For this your onMessage must have "my message" value

Comment: I guess you are telling me to check the received message. Well, the first line of the function onMessage is Log.i(TAG, "Received message"); . That log entry isn't shown, so the function onMessage is never called, it seems that the client doesn't receive the message.

Comment: ok. is there any method like this in your onMessage method? : generateNotification(arg0, arg1.getStringExtra("your message tag")); if yes replace "your mesage tag" with "my message" . Hope this will help you.

Comment: There is a generateNotification method, but the first arg is the context and the second one is a static string ("From GCM: you got message!"). generateNotification(context, getString(R.string.gcm_message));

Comment: Done. Still the same, the function isn't called. Is there any way to know the error code or something like that? Just returning false is a bit frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it from https to http

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
```

Answer (score -1):

try this http://2mecode.blogspot.hk/2013/01/google-cloud-messaging-php.html

hope it can help you

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO - please note that link-only answers are generally frowned upon - answers should be complete and use links for references, not for the entire answer content. I recommend editing your answer to put the relevant code (and explanation of how it will help).